# managing big .rda files in shiny server in an Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, shiny, shiny-server

I'm using Shiny Server on an Amazon EC vm (4cpus 8gb of ram running ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

The problem I have is the following : 
when I run my shiny App locally, everything is good, and I don't get any errors loading my **250MB .rda file**. However, when run it on the Amazon instance, my app just disconnects after hitting the button that triggers the prediction using the model stored on my .rda file.
I tried a dummy model stored in a **small (25MB) .rda file** and the App worked correctly. So my question is, Does the free version of Shiny server have a limitation on the size of the files ? and if not, any workaround for this problem ?

EDIT: I tried the App on a VM with the same specs, but running ubuntu 14.04, I still have the same problem.

Comment: I know it might be a silly question but how big is your `EC2` instance?

Comment: @PorkChop it's a 4CPUs, 8GB RAM instance.

Comment: Be specific on the instance type you use.  Otherwise, we will assume it is a t2.medium and ignore the question.

Comment: @mootmoot I edited the post to include the needed info.

Comment: 1. Free shiny server doesn't support multiprocessor, it depends on your OS to distribute the cpu load. 2. Check the EC2 instance resource monitor log 3. Avoid t2 instance for apps that need continuous workload.  4. Try it on bigger instance with more RAM. e.g. m4.xlarge , monitor the load.
 

https://www.r-bloggers.com/shiny-server-open-source-edition-solution-for-cpu-bound-apps/